# Problem centering div in IE8 with CSS

Tags: html, css

basicaly I have the following HTML/CSS Layout

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="main">
        <h1>TEST</h1>
    </div> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#cont {
  width: 100%;
  background: #ddd;
}
#main {
  width: 900px;
  background: #fff;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

This works fine in FF, safari, Chrome and Opera but IE8 still aligns the "main" div to the left.

Does anyone know what the problem might be? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Works better if you don't abbreviate your CSS class names: `#cont` isn't the same as `#container` :)

Comment: @Eric, yeah, I was hoping that was just a typo but you might be right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change either the css `#cont` to `#container` or the `id` of the `div` to `cont`.

Works fine for me in IE8. http://jsfiddle.net/5M6X9/

Answer (score 0):

did you define a doc type?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

Futhermore get rid of the width: 100% on the first div and body must have padding: 0 and margin: 0

Answer (score 0):

IE needs a correct DOC Type!

I always use

```
#main{
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

and the width:100% is not necessary.

replace 0 for top and bottom margins or

```
#main{
  margin:30px auto 0;
}
```

for just top-margin